# Membership credential verification failed in kentico

Tags: asp.net, .net, active-directory, membership-provider, kentico

I am trying to integrate AD authentication in Kentico. It keeps fail while i authenticate with error message in event viewer as below :

```
Event code: 4006 
Event message: Membership credential verification failed. 
Event time: 4/29/2016 2:01:41 PM 
Event time (UTC): 4/29/2016 8:31:41 AM 
Event ID: 2feb1b6bc79f4da19d398241d4c4a3fd 
Event sequence: 2 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/11/ROOT-22-131063922814527564 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico9\CMS\ 
    Machine name: BG4WS0612 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 8820 
    Process name: iisexpress.exe 
    Account name: SONATA\vikash.kr 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:1469/CMSPages/logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=/ 
    Request path: /CMSPages/logon.aspx 
    User host address: ::1 
    User: administrator 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Forms 
    Thread account name: SONATA\vikash.kr 

Name to authenticate: vikash.kr 

Custom event details:
```

Please see my web config settings:

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CMSConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=BG4WS0612;Initial Catalog=Kentico9;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=axxxxxxx;Connect Timeout=60"/>

        <add name="CMSADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://1xx.2x.15x.15x/DC=QTLxxxxLT,DC=LOCAL"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

and see below:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CMSProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CMSProvider" type="CMS.MembershipProvider.CMSMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="CMSConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true"/>

        <remove name="CMSADProvider"/>
        <add name="CMSADProvider" type="CMS.MembershipProvider.CMSADMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="CMSADConnectionString" connectionUsername="QTxxRSLT\vikash.kr"   connectionPassword="xxxx23"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure SONATA\vikash.kr account has needed permission to access/read AD?

Comment: Hey Roman, Thanks for your reply, Just now i am able to access ad login in another system and got to know that why it was not login in my system because of my system username and ad login username both are same so it may be the cause of conflicting and not working. Thanks man i have done it through my self only.